# How to convert XML Word Documents to DOCX?

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, ms-office, python-docx

I have been given a series of folders with large amounts of Word documents in .xml formatting. They each contain some VBA code, but the code on all of them has already been run, so I don't need to keep this.

I need to print all of the files in each folder, but due to constraints on XML files on the network, I can't simply mass-print them from Windows Explorer, so I need to convert them to .docx (or .doc) first.

How can I go about doing this? I tried a simple python script using python-docx:

```
import os
from docx import Document
folderPath=<folderpath>
fileNamesList=os.listdir(folderPath)
for xmlFileName in fileNamesList:
    currentDoc=Document(os.path.join(folderPath,xmlFileName))
    docxFileName=xmlFileName.replace('.xml','.docx')
    currentDoc.save(os.path.join(folderPath,docxFileName))
    currentDoc.close()
```

This gives:

`docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at <first file name>.xml`

I'm guessing this is because python-docx isn't meant to open .xml files, but that's a pretty uneducated guess. Searching around for this error, all I can find are problems with it not being installed properly (which it is, as far as I can tell) or using .doc files instead of .docx.

Am I simply using python-docx incorrectly? If not, is there are more suitable package or technique I should be using?

Comment: When the file is not a valid or an empty docx file, that kind of exception is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear just what sort of files those `.xml` files are, but I suspect they are a transitional format used I think in Word 2003, which was XML-based, but not the Open Packaging Convention (OPC) format used in Word documents since Word 2007.

`python-docx` is not going to read those, now or ever, so you'll either need to convert them to `.docx` format or parse the XML directly.

If I had Windows available, I suppose I would use VBA to write a short conversion script and then work with the `.docx` files using `python-pptx`. I would start by seeing if Word could load the `.xml` file and go from there.

You might be able to find a utility to do a bulk conversion, but I didn't find any on a quick search.

If all you're interested in is a one-time print, and Word will load the files, then a VBA script for that without the conversion step might be a good option. `python-docx` doesn't print `.docx` files, only read and write them.

Comment: That makes sense, no idea why I didn't think of using VBA. This is something I'll be having to do semi-regularly, so having a script handy to deal with it is a priority if I can manage it, though for this batch I ended up throwing something awful together with `pyautogui` to open and print each file. The equivalent VBA script would hopefully run a lot better, though.

Thanks very much for the help :)