# Сonvert xml to docx for python

Tags: python, xml, docx, converters

Please tell me how to convert xml to docx. I understand that xml is an archived docx. How to convert it? Or maybe someone knows another way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630270/how-to-convert-xml-word-documents-to-docx), this answer on your question?

Comment: You have it the wrong way around. A `.docx`file is a zipfile containing some very specialised `.xml` files, but also other filetypes such as images. The xml schema that MS Word uses is quite complex.

Comment: @Bernana Yes, it's something similar, but there is no solution there. I thought maybe someone had already encountered.

Comment: @BoarGules What do you recommend?

Comment: That depends very much on what the xml represents and what sort of "conversion" you have in mind.

Comment: @BoarGules I have an xml file that contains a docx file. that is, if we open xml with the right mouse button->open with->MW, then we will open a docx file, and with all the formatting. I need to do the same thing, but automated. It is also advisable to save the docx file.